# How to create a login by specifying the database or with several connection strings in a Web API?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

How to create a login by specifying the database or with several connection strings in a Web API?

I have the following code and I want the user to be able to choose his database at the beginning of the session, so that he sends the credentials and at the same time the name of the connection string obtained in a drop-down menu in the .html login.

```
    //project AccesoDatos..
//OwinContext Is it unattainable from this project? What I can do?


       namespace AccesoDatos
{
    public  class DaoConexion: MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public Database DB { get; set; }
        public Database DaoConexionDbContext()
        {
            ///Obtain claims from the security database.
            var claims = ((ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity);
            var claim = claims.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "ConnectionStringsName").FirstOrDefault();

            if (claim ==null)
            {
                ///Get the DefaultConnection of the web.config 
                ///To authenticate the user and return the claims of the security database.
                string DefaultConnection;
                DefaultConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
                return DB =new SqlDatabase(DefaultConnection);
            }
            return DB = new SqlDatabase(claim.Value);
        }       
    }
}
```

connection consumption

```
//project PersonaES..
    namespace ServiciosEntidad.PersonaES.Repositorio
    {
        public class PersonaESRepositorio : DaoConexion, IPersonaESRepositorio
        {        
    public List<Persona> ListarPersonas()
            {
        DB = DaoConexionDbContext();
        DbCommand command = DB.GetStoredProcCommand("spListarPersonas");
        DataSet ds = this.DB.ExecuteDataSet(command);
        if (ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Count() == 0)
            return null;
        return ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new Persona
        {                    
            Tipo = row.Field<string>("Tipo"),
            Id = row.Field<int>("Id"),
            PrimerNombre = row.Field<string>("PrimerNombre"),
            SegundoNombre = row.Field<string>("SegundoNombre"),
            PrimerApellido = row.Field<string>("PrimerApellido")
         }}}}
```

img example.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kRv5glvHzsr5vNlvgmsFZW2HlJ7YJqDa

My application manages the SOAP architecture. I have a project with the name: `DataAccess`, with a `DaoConexion` class. Using the database class of (`Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data`) which in turn implements `DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase`, Instancio this project in each of the repositories, each repository is a project within the same solution.

These projects are injected into my Web API but the API has its own connection string. My intention is to modify the connection string used by the `DataAccess` project, depending on the current connection of the Web API, in the execution of the Web API

```
//main project Taller (WEB API C#)
    namespace Taller.Models
    {
        public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
        {
            public IdentityContext(string connectionStringName) 
                : base(connectionStringName)
            {
            }
            public static IdentityContext Create(string connectionStringName)
            {          
                return new IdentityContext(connectionStringName);
            }
        }
    }
```

The user sends the name of the connection string.

```
//main project Taller (WEB API C#)
    namespace Taller.Controllers
    {
        public class UtilidadController : ApiController
        {
        [HttpPost]
                public string GetConectarDbEmpresa(Empresas empresas)
            {
                if (empresas.ConnectionStringsName =="")
                {
                     empresas.ConnectionStringsName = "DefaultConnection";
                    IdentityContext.Create(empresas.ConnectionStringsName);
                }
                else
                {
                    IdentityContext.Create(empresas.ConnectionStringsName);               
                }
                return "Te as Conectado a la Empresa Por Favor ingresa tus Credenciales: ";
            }}}
```

the user already specified in the login session what BD to use, I do not know how to save the connectionStringName temporarily while the user has the active session

```
//main project Taller (WEB API C#)

    public partial class Startup{...
   public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app){...

        var claims = ((ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity);
        var claim = claims.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "ConnectionStringsName").FirstOrDefault();
        if (claim != null)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => IdentityContext.Create(claim.Value));
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        }
        else
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => IdentityContext.Create("DefaultConnection"));
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        }
```

Comment: I have not managed to force the architecture.
Please someone help me

Comment: the code of the question is already corrected ... if someone has a better way, post your answer